# learn to raft vs learn to go rafting

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

Which of the following sentences sound more natural?

- I learned to raft on holiday.
- I learned to go rafting on holiday.

Comment: You might want to share some thoughts or research so the question is not closed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sports:
the activity: to go rafting or to raft.
to go skiing or to ski, to go surfing or to surf, to skate or go skating

learning it:
to learn to raft
to learn to ski
to learn to skate
etc.

Though you can say: to learn rafting or to learn surfing, to learn to [do something] sounds more idiomatic.

You don't "learn" to "go" do a sports activity really. You learn how to do or play the sport.

Comment: Every dictionary I've checked says "learn to do something"  For example, Cambridge says, [ + to infinitive ] I'm learning to play the piano. But, Longman does not list "raft" as a verb. That's why I wanted to ask this question. I'm still confused about "learn rafting" though. I've checked Longman, Oxford, Cambridge and Macmillan and I haven't found a single example like "learn surfing" or "learn rafting". For example, Macmillan says, "learn to do something: The children are learning to swim this summer."

Comment: @jeepers I answered your question: "learn to play the piano is RIGHT. "Learn to go verb[ing] is not. learn to ski, learn to raft, learn to read. **OF course, learn to swim, read, play, whatever. NO: learn to go swimming. No, no, no.